# In django-taggit, how to get tags for objects that are associated with a specific user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, tags, django-taggit

I have a series of objects that are associated with specific users, like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class LibraryObject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Book(LibraryObject):
    summary = models.TextField()

class JournalArticle(LibraryObject):
    excerpt = models.TextField()

# ...etc.
```

I know that I can retrieve all tags like this:

```
>>> from taggit.models import Tag
>>> Tag.objects.all()
```

But how can I retrieve all tags that are associated with a specific user? I'm imagining something like `Tag.objects.filter(owner=me)`, but of course that doesn't work.

For reference, here's the [django-taggit documentation](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've came across a similar problem, and here is my solution:

```
tags = Tag.objects.filter(book__owner=me)
tags |= Tag.objects.filter(journalarticle__owner=me)
tags = tags.distinct()
```

hope it will help~